# How to use IPython's system shell profile as your default shell (Windows 7 64-bit)

Tags: python, ipython, windows-7-x64

I've used IPython as my system shell for a long time on Linux, and now that I've recently begun using Windows again, I'd like to continue doing so in the Windows shell.

The IPython docs (for the stable version 0.12), explain how to configure IPython for this:
http://infocus.cc/?url=http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/shell.html&p=4384&b=wk&l=91&t=334&w=855&h=150

However, I've looked in the start menu for a link to the "pysh" script (after installing IPython using both pip and the Windows executable installer available from ipython.org), but it's not anywhere in my start menu. I've also tried the other method described in on that page, adding `import ipy_profile_sh` to my profile script in my .ipython config directory, but that didn't work either.

Does anyone know how to pull this off? Thanks!

Comment: Note the warning at the top of that page, indicating that its contents  are out of date as of IPython-0.11.  The pysh profile has not been updated to the new APIs yet.

Answer (score 4):

All is not lost. IPython 0.13, and probably 0.12, still ship with the "pysh" profile, which at least gives you a nice shell prompt, and maybe some other minor additions.

To use this, first do:

```
ipython profile create pysh
```

This will copy over the shipped pysh profile to your user directory. If you now startup ipython with:

```
ipython --profile=pysh
```

... it will make use of this profile.

Comment: Actually you should use the "sh" profile, it's Newer and Better somehow. "pysh" is deprecated and is supposed to be removed eventually.

Comment: I just tried with 0.13.2, but "ipython profile create sh" and then "ipython --profile=sh" just gave me the stock ipython profile. Maybe sh is just in development? @boxed

Comment: So your advice is not applicable to stable IPython (as is the case for the original question), but a good tip for people using dev. :)